# Conditionally add action to element with Ember Handlebars

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I've scoured the Internet for an answer to this problem but have found none. I have a custom SideNavigationLinkComponent that wraps an `<li>` around an `<a>` tag and possibly a `<ul>` of child links.

The anchor tag looks something like this:

```
 <a href="{{unbound menu.parent.link}}" {{action "toggle"}}>
    ...
 </a>
```

"Why aren't you using `{{link-to}}`?" you ask. It's because `menu.parent.link` isn't guaranteed to be a valid route; sometimes it's something like `#nav-collapsible-44`, which breaks `{{link-to}}`.

Anyway, the point of the anchor tag in the code above is to serve as **either** a top-level link to another Ember page **or** a button that causes a collapsible list of sublinks to drop down.

My problem is that as long as I have `{{action "toggle"}}` on the anchor tag, the **link doesn't go anywhere** (but the collapsibles work, which is part of what I want). So I need to be able to **conditionally add an `{{action}}`** so that I can create either links that go to other pages or buttons that cause dropdowns to expand depending on the value of some boolean condition I have.

I don't want to have to do this:

```
{{#if condition}}
  <a href="{{unbound menu.parent.link}}" {{action "toggle"}}>
    ...
  </a>
{{else}}
  <a href="{{unbound menu.parent.link}}">
    ...
  </a>
{{/if}}
```

which so far has been the only way I've found to solve this problem. There's a lot of HTML in the anchor tags and sure, I could use a partial to DRY this structure up a bit, but that's just putting band-aids on a banana split.

I've also tried

```
if(!condition){
  return true; 
}
```

in my "toggle" action but it had no effect.

Comment: Why not just pass the `menu.parent.link` as a parameter to the `toggle` action and handle the logic for transitioning (or not) there?

Comment: I thought of that too, then I saw [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22432933/2069194). I don't think it makes sense to turn my navigation link into a view, either. And since it's nested inside a larger component, routing would get tricky real fast. But I'm open to suggestions!

Comment: You should definietly do it the way as @rogMaHall pointed out. If you need to create component that is not issolated from context then it should be a view.

Comment: Hi @IGNIS, did you find a solution? am also in search of a solution for this kind of problem. Can you share your solution here?

Comment: I'm sorry @PraveenKumar, but I did not. :( I think I had to resort to the solution I proposed in the question (i.e.,, use the Handlebars conditionals and a bit of copy-pasting). You could also try the solution suggested by the other commenters on here, though as I recall, I had a problem with that as well. Wish I could be more help. Good luck!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [closure actions](http://miguelcamba.com/blog/2016/01/24/ember-closure-actions-in-depth/) such as:

```
<a href="{{unbound menu.parent.link}}" onclick={{if condition (action 'toggle')}}> 
    ...
</a>
```

Answer (score 8):

You can also use  [(optional) helper from ember-composable-helpers](https://github.com/DockYard/ember-composable-helpers#optional)

```
<a {{action (optional (if foo (action "nextQuestion") null))}}>
```

Comment: Or [`noop`](https://github.com/DockYard/ember-composable-helpers#noop). It was helpful to me with the `on` modifier, which requires a function as the second param, no `null` or `undefined`.