# Ember transitionToRoute cleanly in a component without sendAction

Tags: ember.js

How can `transitionToRoute` be called cleanly from within an Ember component?

It works with injecting a controller into the component and calling the controller's `transitionToRoute` function, however I'd like something a little more elegant if possible.

What it currently looks like inside the component's javascript:

```
// this.controller is injected in an initializer
this.controller.transitionToRoute("some.target.route.name");
```

What would be nicer in the component's javascript:

```
transitionToRoute("some.target.route.name");
```

*One goal is do this without using `sendAction` as this particular component has a single purpose and should always transition to the same route. There's no need for any other Ember artifacts to be aware of the route this component always transitions to, there's no need for the associated indirection. The responsibility for the target route is owned by this component.*

Comment: Related question that may be of interest to readers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22389384/transitiontorouteroute-from-inside-component

Answer (score 65):

---

---

**UPDATE** Please see the other more recent answers for how to achieve this with less code in newer Ember versions, and vote those up if they work for you - Thanks!

---

---

Inject the `router` into the components and call `this.get('router').transitionTo('some.target.route.name')`.

To inject the `router` into all components, write an initializer at `app/initializers/component-router-injector.js` with the following contents:

```
// app/initializers/component-router-injector.js
export function initialize(application) {
  // Injects all Ember components with a router object:
  application.inject('component', 'router', 'router:main');
}

export default {
  name: 'component-router-injector',
  initialize: initialize
};
```

Sample usage in a component:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  actions: {
    submit: function() {
      this.get('router').transitionTo('some.target.route.name');
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: For 2017 readers: The problem with `sendAction` is that you have to keep bubbling that up if your components are nested.  If you can send an action directly to the route from the component, it becomes a non-issue.  Ember will eventually have routable components that allows you to talk directly to the route. Until then, use the the `ember-route-action-helper` to call a method directly on the route that your component exists on - such as `transitionTo('name-of-route')`. Read more here: http://dockyard.com/blog/2016/02/19/best-practices-route-actions

Answer (score 13):

**Jan 22, 2018 update**
As of [Ember 2.15](https://www.emberjs.com/blog/2017/09/01/ember-2-15-released.html), phase 1 of the [public router service](https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/blob/master/text/0095-router-service.md) is implemented.
Transition to a route from inside a component:

```
import { inject as service } from '@ember/service';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  router: service(),

  actions: {
    someAction() {
        this.get('router').transitionTo('index');
    }
  }

});
```

Answer (score 5):

Use
`router: service()`

instead of 
`router: service('-routing')`

```
import Component from '@ember/component';
import {inject as service} from '@ember/service';

export default Component.extend({
  router: service(),

  actions: {
    onClick(params) {
      let route = this.getMyRoute(params);
      this.get('router').transitionTo(route);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: This is the **only** legitimate answer on this page, circa Ember ~3.11

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use the router only in a specific **component** or **service** or **controller**, you may try this:

Initialize an attribute with the private service `-routing`. The `-` because it's not a public API yet.

```
router: service('-routing'),
```

And then inside any action method or other function inside the service or component:

```
this.get('router').transitionTo(routeName, optionalParams);
```

Note: It'll be `transitionToRoute` in a controller.

Answer (score 2):

You can use container to get access to any needed part of application. To get application controller :

```
this.container.lookup('controller:application')
```

But what about structure of application - components should generate events - so my opinion it's better to use sendAction. Cause in future you can get situation, when you need to filter such behavior ( for example ) or other application-specific logic before transition

Comment: This is not recommended as it uses an internal API that could break. Actually the access to the container started to be deprecated on Ember 2.3 I think, and it's now replaced with a different interface (`getOwner` I think).