# How to pass an object to link-to + queryParams in Ember?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-router, ember.js-2

I'm currently in a situation that I need to pass one object to `{{link-to}}`, but `queryParams` does not accept objects `{key:value}`. I need this feature because I'm using this component in different templates. The reason for doing that is that one template uses some keywords to use as a filter that the other template does not use and vice-versa.

I started using my own helper to generate the link, but I realize that the anchor my helper was generating was reloading the whole page and link-to does not do that. I'd like to reproduce that behavior, because there are other variables set on the view which I'm using and they all get reset to their default values whenever I reload the page

Is there a smart way to create a link using objects now? I saw some answers but they were all related to ember 1.+ and canary. In all of the answers they were saying it was not possible. I wonder if people have implemented this now or if a solution for this problem is being used currently and I could not find...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I really could not find a way to do this. What I've done instead was creating `{{actions}}` inside my anchors and then I used `transitionTo()` to simulate the behavior of `{{link-to}}`.

A nice way of doing that can be seen here

[Ember transitionToRoute cleanly in a component without sendAction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30697674/ember-transitiontoroute-cleanly-in-a-component-without-sendaction)